# Why does Firefox not acknowledge camera and mic access on web page?

Tags: windows, firefox, webcam

Gave Firefox camera and microphone access, but message requesting it displays and partly blocks the web page. On Windows 10 with the current version of Firefox on an HP desktop, a NexiGo N930AF USB webcam. Trying to access a video visit on the Kaiser website (mydoctor.kaiserpermanente.org). I have allowed access to the camera and mic via Firefox settings.
The exact message is

```
Camera and Microphone Access Required
Before you can start your visit, you must allow access to your camera and microphone.
```

It sounds like a message from the Kaiser website. This doesn't happen with Edge.

Comment: what's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Privacy in the Control panel. There will be a link a bit down the page  and Allow Applications to access the camera and mic.

Then reload the webpage and the browser should now ask for permissions before they use the devices the first time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nope. In FF 99.0.1, Win 10 Home 64 bit, there is no Allow Applications section. As already stated I already allow camera and mic access in Privacy & Security, Permissions settings.